# Find the closest number to a target in JavaScript without using arrays

Tags: javascript

1. Hi, could anyone explain to me how to find the closest number to a
   target. I am creating a function that  get 3 parameters and return
   the **true** if true the user win and **false** if the computer win.
2. I have already tried to look for it but I found only solution using arrays
   there is anything I can do without using them?

   ```
   function updateScore(humanScore, computerScore, generateTarget) {
   if(abs(humanScore) < abs(genrateTarget)) {
   return true} else{return false}
   };
   ```

Comment: Why would you need arrays if there are just two scores? Just get the absolute values of the differences, and compare them with an `if` statement.

Comment: All right i will keep it in mind for the next time i will ask something the thing is that i try already with abs value but i do not understund how it could works into it

Comment: If you already tried, show what you tried. It's probably a simple mistake and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand completely what you want to convey but i guess you want to generate a random number and check whose answer is nearer. You can use this:

```
function updateScore(humanScore, computerScore, generateTarget) {
    return(Math.abs(humanScore - generateTarget) < Math.abs(computerScore - generateTarget) ? humanScore : computerScore); 
}
```

This will return the guess which is nearer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much now i understund that the value to be return is the nearest to 0 and not to the target i was just confused on how use abs() thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd subtract the target from both scores, and compare the absolute difference:

```js
function updateScore(humanScore, computerScore, generateTarget){
    return Math.abs(humanScore - generateTraget) < Math.abs(computerScore - generateTarget);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i was using abs() in the wrong way like that is much more clear